# How do I test a Rails Controller from a Rails Engine in a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a rails controller from an engine in a gem with a method OrdersController#populate.  I'm changing the class with a after_action like this so that a user can only have one line item in the cart.

```
module Spree
  module Controllers
    module Orders
      module SingleSubscriptionAddDecorator
        def cart_path
          checkout_state_path(@order.checkout_steps.first)
        end

        def self.prepended(base)
          base.after_action(
            :ensure_one_in_cart,
            only: :populate
          )
        end

        private
        def ensure_one_in_cart
          if @order.line_items.length > 1
            @order.line_items[1..-1].each { |li| li.delete }
          end
          @order.line_items.first.update_attribute(:quantity, 1) if @order.line_items.first.quantity > 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Spree::OrdersController.prepend(Spree::Controllers::Orders::SingleSubscriptionAddDecorator)
```

I'd like to add rspec around this controller behavior, but can't access the gems routes from within my rspec.  How do I test this behavior?

Thank!

Comment: Are you creating a Rails engine yourself or an application?

Comment: If you are creating a gem than you would mount the routes in the dummy application (the app in `spec/dummy`) and test them with a request spec. But what you are doing looks like it should be handled in the model layer as its buisness logic.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Creating an application with a gem that provides the engine containing the controller.

Comment: Have you mounted the engine in your `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: It works fine in development and the staging site. Just not in specs.